# file upload using https error?

Tags: java, https, ioexception

My code is,

```
 Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
    systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore",    
   System.getProperty("catalina.home")+fs+".keystore");
    System.setProperties(systemProps);

  try {
  // Open a secure connection.
  URL url = new URL( "https://192.168.6.45:8181/erp_adapter/UploadFile" );
  String requestParams = "uid=sdfn&password=rsdftesan&active=y&type=F";
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  // Set up the connection properties
  con.setRequestProperty( "Connection", "close" );
  con.setDoInput(true);
  con.setDoOutput(true);
  con.setUseCaches(false);
  con.setConnectTimeout( 30000 );
  con.setReadTimeout( 30000 );
  con.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
  con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
  con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString(requestParams.length()) );

  // Set up the user authentication portion of the handshake with the private
  // key provided by NAIMES Tech Support.
  //   Based on an example posted by Torsten Curdt on his blog:
  //     http://vafer.org/blog/20061010073725 (as of Nov, 2009)
  File pKeyFile = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.home")+fs+".keystore");
  String pKeyPassword = "UB#20abba";
  KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
  KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
  InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
  //byte[] Password=pKeyPassword.getBytes();
  keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
  keyInput.close();
```

Here it shows an error as,

> java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
>           at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.util.DerValue.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
>           at com.gofrugal.raymedi.erp.util.AidapClient.main(AidapClient.java:58)

Can any one help me what is the problem and to resolve it?

Comment: You posted two code segments which aren't related to each other. There is no uploading bits in any part of your code. Can you be a bit more specific about where the error is coming from. From current stack trace, it doesn't related to https or file uploading as you said in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The keystore you're trying to load probably isn't an instance of a Sun PKCS12 keystore.  Issue the following command to find out the type of the keystore...

```
keytool -list -keystore <keystore_location>
```

You'll find output that looks like...

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 76 entries

...
```

In this case the Keystore is a JKS keystore (which I'm guessing yours is too) and you'll want to do

```
KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

Instead of what you have.

Comment: This also applies when using jarsigner, make sure not to specify storetype as pkcs12